# find files NOT belonging to group

Tags: linux, find, groups

How do I find files not belonging to particular group?

```
find /home -group NOT test
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`find /home -not -group test` or `find /home ! -group test`

The exclamation inverts the match. From `man find`:

```
 ! expr True  if  expr  is false.  This character will also usually need

 -not expr
          Same as ! expr, but not POSIX compliant.
```

If you want the group it does belong to in the output:

```
find /home ! -group test -printf "%p:%g\n"
./lots/573:root
...
```

Some more information on using find:
[How do I master the UNIX find command?](https://serverfault.com/questions/29489/how-do-i-master-the-unix-find-command)

Comment: +1 - didn't know you could do that.

Comment: +1 -- good trick, didn't know this was an option either... :]

Answer (score -1):

Do a grep excluding the things you don't want?

Comment: like how do I get the groups listed with find? I would appreciate an example

Comment: How about instead you use Kyle's answer, which is a better solution.